# How do I put a border around some button text without also putting it around the div's left-hand padding?

Tags: html, css, button

How do I put a border around some button text without also putting it around the div's left-hand padding? I would prefer not to use JS, Flexbox, or CSS3.

This is what I've got so far:

```css
    .button-1 {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: inline;
    margin: -5px auto 0 auto;}
```

```html
<a href="#1" class="button-1">hello</a><a href="#1" class="button-1">cheerio</a>
```

Comment: what about margin instead padding ?

Comment: You're right - thanks! D'y'know, I'd tried that and since it puts the border too close to the text I thought "this can't be the way", not realising the distance to the border can then be controlled using `padding`. This is what comes of coding when you're tired. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying for this

```
<button><span style="border:1px solid; padding 10px; margin-left:10px">Border Around Text</span></button>
```